# Не выводит результат

Tags: c, массивы

Обнуляю массив,заполняю массив с конца и хочу вывести его на экран, но выдает ошибку такого рода: Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'A' was corrupted

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
const int N = 10;
void main(void) {
char A[N];
int c = 0,i=0,r=0,j=0,l=0;

for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    A[i] = 0;
}
i = 0;
while ((A[N-i] = getchar()) != '\n')
    i = i + 1;

for (i = N-1; i >0 ; i--) {
    printf("%c", A[i]-'0');
}
_getch();
```

}

Например,ввожу 123 , а на выходе получается набор символов, а не введенных чисел

Comment: Но ошибку вы нам не скажете, потому что хотите убедиться в существовании телепатов?

Comment: В последнем цикле `i > 0` должно быть. Вы выходите за пределы массива, скорее всего..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char A[N];
```

Итак, в массиве `N` элементов - от `0` до `N-1`. Запомним.

```
i = 0;
while ((A[N-i] = getchar()) != '\n')
```

На первой итерации пишем в элемент `N-i`, т.е. с номером `N`. Ы?